# How to validate current user permissions for a given Term Store Group using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-store, csom, jsom

I can't seem to find a way to check for the current user permissions for a term store group or term set in Sharepoint Online.
I know the REST interface does not support any kind of interaction with the taxonomy service, so I've already discarded it has an option, but I'm wondering if this is achievable through CSOM or JSOM.

The reason I need to do this is because we have a custom page to create terms under specific term sets and I want to check the user's write access to this term sets before letting him do any editing.